# Why error when scraping a (dynamic?) table from webpage using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, excel, beautifulsoup, export

I am trying to scrape the tables from Great Schools .com using beautiful soup, but am running into an error.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tbody'
```

I cannot find an attribute descriptor of the table in the HTML...is that the problem? Is the table dynamic such that I should be using other packages or code? I want to turn this into a data table that I can export to Excel. How should I do that? Code is below.

Thanks in advance.

---

```
import pandas as pd

import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.greatschools.org/pennsylvania/bethlehem/schools/?tableView=Overview&view=table" 
html_content = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

school_table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class":""})
school_table_data = school_table.tbody.find_all("tr")
```

Comment: If you load the page and look at the source code (not inspect element) you will not see the table. So you are right. The table is loading asynchronous, so you will need to use another package to fetch the data needed. Maybe you could fetch the data from the same place they do?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
import re
import json
import pandas as pd


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    match = re.search(r'gon.search=(\{.+})', r.text).group(1)
    goal = json.loads(match)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(goal['schools'])
    return df


main("https://www.greatschools.org/pennsylvania/bethlehem/schools/?tableView=Overview&view=table")
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. But there is some extra text that I am not sure how to get rid of in the output. Do you know how to strip it out? For example, all the street addresses look like this: {'street1': '3890 Jacksonville Road', 'street2...